# Flash + Box2d pool game breaks online because shots are not transmitted precisely, why?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, box2d

I'm, working on this pool game:

http://cassinlwbg.facebook.joyent.us/quickpool/main.swf

Please open it in TWO browser windows you will see that the 2 player modus starts.

When you make a shot, every shot gets copied to the other player.

Unfortunately it is not precise enough.

The player makes the shot with this code:

```
protected function makeShot(str:Number, ang:Number):void {

   var vx = str * Math.cos(ang);
   var vy = str * Math.sin(ang);

   var vel = _whiteBall.body.GetLinearVelocity();

   vel.x += (vx * 10);
   vel.y += (vy * 10);

   _whiteBall.body.SetLinearVelocity(vel);

  }
```

After that I send the STRENGTH and ANGLE arguments over my socket server to the other player.

They arrive EXACTLY the same (tested), even after String to Number converting.

Then I apply this to the remote player, as the remote shot, like this:

```
//run remote shot
public function applyMove(s:Number, ang:Number){
   makeShot(s, angle);
}
```

Still, after few shots, the game and the ball positions are different...which breaks the game flow.

Does anybody know why?

Both game files are the same, as you can see.

What are there so much deviations?

Regards,
Mirza

Answer (score 3):

It could be performance differences affecting time intervals on which Box2D doing the numerical integration. You need to synchronize positions somehow. First thing comes to mind is to choose one machine as master, other as slave and copy master's positions to slave, eliminating differences while they're small.

Comment: This is how I'd do it. Designate one client as the master (doesn't really matter which) that calculates the positions, then synchronize the clients by sending the updated positions to the slave(s). Otherwise, there's a bunch of things that can go wrong; rounding errors, timing issues, etc.

Comment: 'Slave' needs smooth animation too, it can't be just feed readymade positions from master. They're both should calculate animation, just sync positions after each shot.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be depending on having exactly the same screen size?

Are you certain you're not using any function that employs rand? Or as time as input?